# Make NavigationBar's titleView larger than itself

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to place an image in the middle of a navigation bar that is bigger then the bar itself. So far I tried to use a UIView with a UIImageView inside and it works quite well as you can see here:

[image]

However as soon as I push another controller and pop back my ImageView gets cropped to the size of the NavigationBar again.

[image]
Any ideas on how to prevent the cropping?

My code so far for iOS 11:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let logo = UIImage(named: "Logo")
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: titleView.frame.width, height: titleView.frame.height)
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = logo
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
}
```

**Edit:** Currently there is a **temporary solution** which uses an observer to overwrite the clipsToBounds property of the view that causes the trouble: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122252/1195661) (shout out to @trungduc for that)

Comment: Your code work perfectly on my simulator https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKCBT.png

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I tried it on the simulator as well. Did you push another controller and then pop back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found why you got this issue. It's because of a private view which has name `_UINavigationBarContentView`. It's a subview of `UINavigationBar`. `navigationItem.titleView` is contained in this view.

[image]

At first time, when you change `navigationItem.titleView`. `_UINavigationBarContentView.clipsToBounds` is `false` .But after you push another controller and pop back, `_UINavigationBarContentView.clipsToBounds` is `true`. That's why `titleView` is cropped.

So i have a **temporary solution**. Each time when `viewController` appears, find this view and change `_UINavigationBarContentView.clipsToBounds` to `false` and layout `titleView`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for view : UIView in (navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
      view.clipsToBounds = false;
    }
    navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for view : UIView in (navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
      view.clipsToBounds = false;
    }
    navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
```

I tried and it works. But i think you shouldn't do something whit it because it's private view. Maybe Apple don't want us do anything with it.

Hope somehow my suggestion can help you. Good luck ;)

**SOLUTION**

Adding observer for `_UINavigationBarContentView.clipsToBounds`, each time when it changes to `false`, set to `true` and update layout of `titleView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  let logo = UIImage(named: "Logo")
  let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
  let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
  imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: titleView.frame.width, height: titleView.frame.height)
  titleView.addSubview(imageView)
  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
  imageView.image = logo
  navigationItem.titleView = titleView
  navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[2].addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "clipsToBounds", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if  (navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[2].isEqual(object))! {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[2].clipsToBounds = false
      self.navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
}

deinit {
  navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[2].removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "clipsToBounds")
}
```

For more detail and easier, you can check my demo here https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/big-title-navigation-bar

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, this will probably help us to find a solution :)

Comment: @palme if you can fix it, please let me know. I am very eager to see how you fix it ;)

Comment: @palme another way is adding observer for `_UINavigationBarContentView.clipsToBounds`. Each time it changes to `false`, change it to `true` again and layout the view. i'm not good at Swift so i can't try it but i think you should try ;)

Comment: I like both of your ideas, thanks for sharing. Unfortunately I have a flickering when I implemented your first approach (maybe you did not see it because you did not call the super functions). I could not get the observer to work to be honest. I know the principle but the delegate for the observer for the property clipsToBounds on the _UINavigationBarContentView was never called.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I can approve, it works great. It will probably be just a temporary solution, as you said, but at least you found a solution. Again thanks for the investigation.

Comment: Welcome ;) . I'm looking forward to see real solution from you.

Comment: As soon as I have production code I will update you. I will edit my first post to show your current solution.

Comment: I still i get a really fast flash of the image but does not happen always! What this might be any ideas?(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(UINavigationBar*)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context { if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"clipsToBounds"]){self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds,object.clipsToBounds);
    if (object.clipsToBounds == YES){dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = false [self.navigationItem.titleView layoutIfNeeded];
    });}}}

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the code in the viewWillAppear method. This way you will add the image to the bar everytime the view appears. However you should then remove the inageview within the viewDidDissappear method. If you need it in several views you could subclass the UIViewController and use this one.

Comment: As @trungduc mentioned, once you go back to the view controller there is the subview _UINavigationBarContentView which is will have clipsToBounds enabled and therefore the titleView will be cut off not matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationBar has UIBarMetrics if you want a custom height but it's not fully interactive.

There's [a bunch of code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html) suggested by apple to actually develop nice things like iMessage app.