# Imageview in navigationbar overlay Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have an navigation bar with a logo that overlaps the tableview for about 30% at the bottom. The view below contains a tableview that is filled with news items. When the apps starts its perfect.

When I click an item for a detail view and return. The imageview is cut off where the tableview starts.

Is there some way to set the imageview always on top?

Thanks.

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
logoView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
[logoView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

UIImageView *workaroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];
[workaroundImageView addSubview:logoView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = workaroundImageView;
```

Comment: You should take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself/47122252#47122252. Maybe it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! haven't seen that yet. Pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could bring the view to front every time the user clicks on your tableview.