# dispatch_async crashes app when re-used

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

I'm using a solution for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself) to make titleView clipsToBounds always true.

I have this in my ViewController and it works well, however, if I leave the ViewController by pressing the back button and then come back, it app crashes at the dispatch_async line.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    if([object isEqual:[[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews] objectAtIndex:2]]) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews] objectAtIndex:2].clipsToBounds = NO;
            [self.navigationItem.titleView layoutIfNeeded];
        });
    }
}
```

Edit:

The only error I get is: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x102d8860)`

The console doesn't provide any information other than `(lldb)`

Comment: When ever you post a question about an error, you must include the complete and exact error message as well as point out the exact line of code causing the error. Please [edit] your question to include these details (do not post this in comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must removeObserver if you go out from viewController.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[2]
     removeObserver:self 
     forKeyPath:@"clipsToBounds"];
}
```

Comment: When I use the swipe gesture to start leaving the ViewController but then I cancel the gesture, the UIImageView is clipped again. Do you know if I can add an observer that would catch this?

Comment: Try add this [[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews] objectAtIndex:2].clipsToBounds = NO;

After [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; and before addObserver in the viewWillAppear

Comment: only viewWillAppear must has addObserver, not didLoad

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews] objectAtIndex:2].clipsToBounds = NO;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[2] addObserver:self
                                                          forKeyPath:@"clipsToBounds"
                                                             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                                             context:nil];
}

Comment: Excellent! This makes the `clipsToBounds` property true even after cancelled back gesture. One last issue is that while the gesture is being performed (moving my finger from left to right), the `imageView` in the `titleView` gets cut off as if the `clipsToBounds` property would be false. Is there a way to edit the property after the swipe gesture has started?

Comment: I make small test, this code works for me while gesture is being performed too:
https://pastebin.com/FUJeWHZi

Answer (score 0):

Check  to your block

```
if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews.count > 1){
…
```