# adding UIImageview in titleview of UINavigationBar not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

So i am trying to add an UIImageview in titleview property of the UINavigationbar using the following code. The issue is that although i put specific size to the UIView that contains the UIImageview which contains the image it does not work as expected. The result is a bigger image in the Navigation bar than the one i set with the CGRectMake. Also in some views it does not align to the center! What am i missing? Is there another way to add the image to the navbar?

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,10.0f,16.0f)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,10.0f,16.0f)];
    
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(10, 16);
    CGFloat marginX = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageSize.width / 2);
    
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(marginX, 11, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage sdk_imageName:@"logo.png"];

    [imageView setImage:image];
    [containerView addSubview:imageView];
    self.navigationItem.titleView=imageView;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a `10x16` image view as the title view?

Comment: You have to size the title view with autolayout constraints. Setting the frame does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code and i found some frame issues and at the bottom you are not passing container view in titleview, that will not render the view as expected.

Please try this one.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width,self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
//containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(60, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
CGFloat marginX = (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width / 2) - (imageSize.width / 2);

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(marginX, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"2.jpg"];

[imageView setImage:image];
[containerView addSubview:imageView];
self.navigationItem.titleView=containerView;
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler approach... use auto-layout constraints for the image view size... centering is handled automatically.

`10x16` image view as the `titleView`:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
titleImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

titleImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

    [titleImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:10.0],
    [titleImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:16.0],
    
]];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works but i need the titleview imageview to become even bigger than the height size of the navigationbar. Is this possible?

Comment: @stefanosn - in the code you posted, it looks like you're trying to use a `10x16` image as the titleView. It's not clear what you mean by making it  *"bigger than the height size of the navigationbar"*.  Maybe mock-up an image of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Check please this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself i have the same problem but can not solve it. I tried using the cliptobounds property but does not seem to work...any help appreciated.

Comment: @stefanosn - ok, that's a very different question. Based on seeing similar questions over many years, the consensus seems to be: make your own custom view instead of using the built-in `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: I have to do it with the navigationbar. No time to change the implementation.