# add observer for clipsToBounds in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to add an observer for clipsToBounds property of any object. I would like to change the property for all subviews of navigationbar when ever a subview changes its state from true to false.

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateClipToBounds) name:@"clipsToBounds" object:nil];
    
-(void)updateClipToBounds{
      for (UIView* view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
            view.clipsToBounds = false;
            [view layoutIfNeeded];
          }
}
```

What am i missing? Never gets triggered. Any help appreciated.

Comment: because it is an observer what do you mean?

Comment: trying to achieve this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself . The guy says i have to use an observer for clipstobounds...

Comment: I thought this code observes for any change on the clipsToBounds property...what should i do then? I need to implement in objective c the same functionality.

Comment: But you already know the answer then why you are asking me?

Comment: Ok but why you asked me "why would it get triggered?" when you already know the answer? Why didn't you say to me at first place "the code will never get triggered because this code just set up a recipient of messages from the Notification Center you need to use KVO"...whats the point of asking me something when you already know i am wrong?

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What i am asking has nothing to do with the question of mine. I asked you why you didn’t tell me from the start your answer when you already know i am wrong and you keep telling me about my question. So i will ask you again. What was your intention for asking me instead of telling me your answer?