# KVO check for change of clipsToBounds of all subviews in an UIView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) example for clipsToBounds property of all subviews in my UIView. I do not quite understand how to change the value in observeValueForKeyPath method. I am using this code:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
        [self.navigationController.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"clipsToBounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
         NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    }
    
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Triggered...")
    }
```

It is triggered when ever i change the property clipToBounds of a subview that exists in the UIView i have. I need to change the value back to false for every trigger that happens. What should i write inside the observeValueForKeyPath to change the clipsToBounds property? Any help appreciated.

Comment: "ViewDidLoad" or "viewDidLoad" ?

Comment: viewDidLoad yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course adding the Observer must be done before it works.
Guessing your typo in "ViewDidLoad" would just never be called because it should be "viewDidLoad".
Apart from that your KVO pattern could look like..

```
static void *kvoHelperClipsToBounds = &kvoHelperClipsToBounds;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.navigationController.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"clipsToBounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&kvoHelperClipsToBounds];
}
    
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == kvoHelperClipsToBounds) {
        NSLog(@"context compared successful...");
        //be careful what you cast to.. i dont check isKindOf here.
        UINavigationBar* navbar = (UINavigationBar*)object;
        if (navbar.subviews.count > 1) {
            __kindof UIView *sub = navbar.subviews[1];
            if (sub.clipsToBounds) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    sub.clipsToBounds = NO;
                    [self.navigationItem.titleView layoutIfNeeded];
                });
            }
        }
    } 

    // or compare against the keyPath
    else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"clipsToBounds"]) {
        NSLog(@"classic Key compare Triggered...");
    }
    else
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

`[super observeValueForKeyPath...]` passes not recognized keyPath to **super** to let super's class KVO work, otherwise those would be ignored if super's implementation would rely on observing them. Which should also explain how you could observe all subviews if needed. But think about that there could be potentially hundrets of subviews triggering observeValueForKeyPath if a subclass of UIView would implement it and all subviews (or the ones you like) would be inherited also from this special subclass.

When you change *clipsToBounds* inside the KVO where you observe it, you possibly invoke a loop, specially when you watch both - old and new values. you would change the property, the property triggers kvo, kvo changes the property, the property triggers kvo and on and on.

set `[self.navigationController.view setClipsToBounds:YES]` to change the property. But if done inside KVO it will trigger KVO again as explained.
Usually you would set *clipsToBounds* in `-initWithFrame:` or in `-initWithCoder:` or via Interface Builder and maybe just observe if it gets changed to adapt some other code.

Sidenote: the context just needs to be unique to distinguish it from other KVO.. it could also be reference to a real objects pointer.

Don't forget added Observers must be removed before deallocation.

Comment: Thanks but how do you change the property value of the subview? This code what does exactly? [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

Comment: Thanks for the updated explanation. What i really need is when the clipsToBounds property changes to true outside of KVO then when it gets inside the KVO to change the property to false from true. Actually i want to implement this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself  but seems like it is not working.

Comment: The idea is to create add in titleview of navigationbar a bigger image than the height of the navigationbar. If i add the image as a subview then when the user slides from one view to another using gestures the image does not fade in and fade out as the left and right bar button items. So i had to add the image to the titleview and now this issue happens with the clipsToBounds property of a subview of the navigationbar...i do not really know what is the best approach for this issue...

Comment: I do not know how to do this...

Comment: Actually i implemented the code from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121427/make-navigationbars-titleview-larger-than-itself and it works. But for some reason i do not understand still there is a really fast flash from times to times. Does not happens always but still there is a really fast flash...

Comment: ;-) some secret. refining your own question (in example this one with some "edit" ) is i think better then commenting a swift thread with a full objc statement. And of course it might flash, because KVO is not earlier triggered then the property changed.
Sidenote: i learned that often it is just better to stick with the OS UI as given instead of tweaking it to much because later this might just break and you have to find again some way to make it work. This applies specially for NavigationViewController stuff.

Comment: and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) is indeed by far the best solution.. because it just works.

Comment: there is no time for me to change the implementation just need to fix this really fast flash...i have spent so many hours on this :)

Comment: Can we chat are you available? this is the code i have put in the observer (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString )keyPath ofObject:(UINavigationBar)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context { if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"clipsToBounds"]){self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds,object.clipsToBounds); if (object.clipsToBounds == YES){dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = false [self.navigationItem.titleView layoutIfNeeded]; });}}}

Comment: `ofObject:(UINavigationBar)object` ? should be `ofObject:(id)object` kvo works for all nsobjects residing on a interface property not just UINavbar.. you should cast the id to `UINavigationBar* navbar = (UINavigationBar*)object;` inside the observer method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240451/discussion-between-stefanosn-and-ol-sen).